# PHP does Not include files when adding function to Script

Tags: php

I got a very strange error in my PHP Script. When I include external files in my Script and Access some variables in the included files every thing works Fine at First. When I wrap my Code in a function and try to call the function from another PHP Script, I get an error saying that some variables are undeclared(those variables from the included files). So bassicly when I wrap my Code in a function the Script cant find external variables, when I dont wrap the Code in a function every thing Works fine.... What could cause this Problem ?

EDIT:

Here is my code I define the variables in:

```
<?php


/* Database config */

$db_host        = 'xxx';
$db_user        = 'xxx';
$db_pass        = 'xxx';
$db_database        = 'xxxr';

/* End config */




$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_database);
// If you are connecting via TCP/IP rather than a UNIX socket remember to add the port number as     a parameter.

?>
```

I want to acces $mysqli

Here is the other code:

```
<?php

  include "connect.php";
  include "push.php";

  function findActions($actionID,$userName)
  {

   $actionID = "X0aUsz7QOC1GCJG9ZnY0UoRWoj35hKFt0LxpwtB8";
   $userName = "janne";

$currentDate = date('d/m/Y H:i');
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$userName."actions WHERE actionID = ?";


  if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query))
   {
$stmt->bind_param('s', $actionID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j,$k,$l);

while ($stmt->fetch())
{
    $result[] = array($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j,$k,$l);


    $startDate = strtotime($j);
    $endDate = strtotime($i);
    $now = time();

    if ($now>= $startDate && $now<= $endDate)
    {

        $message = $e.":\n".$a;

        $body['aps'] =
        array(
                'alert' => $message,
                'sound' => 'default'
            );
        $payload = json_encode($body);



        pushMessage($payload);


    }
   }
   }
     else
    {
    echo "Error";
  }
  }




 ?>
```

I tried with global but it did not help :(

Comment: [VARIABLE SCOPE!](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're witnessing an issue with [variable scoping](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). By default, your function looks up variables declared in the *local* scope. You can direct your function to look up variables in the *global* scope by declaring the variables defined in your external file as `global`:

```
function foo() {
    global $bar, $baz, $qux;
}
```

Assuming `$bar`, `$baz`, and `$qux` are variables assigned in your external file, once declared as `global`, they will be accessible from within the scope of your function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wrapping an included file in a function then any variables will be defined within the scope of the function. That is, they will become local variables, and not visible from the global context.

What you do about this depends on the code you have and what you're trying to achieve.